# Spring Security 3 + GAE - Do I really need the whole stack?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-security, basic-authentication, facebook-authentication

I was wondering if it's possible to integrate Spring Security 3 into a GAE application without having to bring the whole Spring + Spring MVC stack with it. Every example I've seen so far has Spring Beans and / or Spring MVC in it

What I want to do is basically implement generic authentication (basic register, login, logout, reset password, etc), include OpenID, Google Authentication, Facebook Authentication, etc all in one place - Spring Security does this quite nice.

Or alternatively, I would prefer to have as few libraries as possible and roll my own, does anyone have a link or some great resource on setting up an authentication service that allows logging in with Custom Login, Google, Facebook, etc without the use of Spring Security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use Spring MVC, but anyway you need spring core.
Answer to this question is highlighted in spring security FAQ:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/faq/faq.html#faq-what-dependencies

More detailed about dependesies you can find here:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#appendix-dependencies

Comment: It says for using Spring Security on a web page, you need spring-security-core and spring-web, spring-web I take it is either Spring MVC or Spring Web Flow?

Comment: it's about separate library:  http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web/3.2.4.RELEASE

both Spring MVC and Spring Web Flow are depend on spring-web, same as Spring Security for web.